# How to change User Agent or set to Desktop Mode on Nativescript IOS Webview

Tags: ios, webview, safari, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I wanted to force the Webview to set it to Desktop mode on Nativescript IOS Webview, currently I have this working on Android by overriding the webview class:

```
/**
     * Initializes webViewInterface for communication between webview and android/ios
     */
    private setupWebViewInterface() {
        let webView: WebView = this.webView.nativeElement;

        webView.on(WebView.loadFinishedEvent, (args: LoadEventData) => {
            if (isAndroid) {
                (<WebView>args.object).android.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                let newUA = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36";
                (<WebView>args.object).android.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);

                (<WebView>args.object).android.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
            }
        });
    }
```

But a bit lost on how to do this on IOS Webview, especially noting that it is using Safari behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set `customUserAgent` on the native view (WKWebView).

```
webView.on(WebView.loadFinishedEvent, (args: LoadEventData) => {
            if (isAndroid) {
                (<WebView>args.object).android.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                let newUA = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36";
                (<WebView>args.object).android.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);

                (<WebView>args.object).android.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
            } else {
                (<WebView>args.object).ios.customUserAgent = "Your user agent";
            }
        });
```